# FindFirstChild() returned nil

Tags: roblox

FindFirstChild(stringval.Value) returned nil some reason

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

local armorFolder = game.ServerStorage.Armor
local stringval = player:WaitForChild("ArmorFolder").Armor

    if stringval.Value ~= nil then
        local armor = armorFolder:FindFirstChild(stringval.Value)
            for i, armorpiece in pairs(armor:GetChildren()) do
                local clone = armorpiece:Clone()
                clone.Parent = player.Character
            end
        end

stringval.Changed:Connect(function()
if stringval.Value ~= nil then
    local armor = armorFolder:FindFirstChild(stringval.Value)
        for i, armorpiece in pairs(armor:GetChildren()) do
            local clone = armorpiece:Clone()
            clone.Parent = player.Character
           end
        end
    end)
end)
```

Error: ServerScriptService.Library.ArmorHandler:8: attempt to index nil with 'GetChildren'

The script is in ServerScriptService by the way. When a player joins, this script will run. The script looks for a piece of armor in ServerStorage that the player owns, and gives it to the player's character.

Comment: Nvm, i fixed it... no need to answer anymore

Comment: Feel free to make a "self answer" below if it would help future readers. You can then tick/check the answer to mark it as solved.